# How to Insert into 2 Tables ProductOrder and ProductOrderLine using VBA & Foreign Keys in Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, foreign-keys

I am newbiew using VBA/FK/SQL server all in one. I am creating simple purchase order workbook user interface in excel.

I have created two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseOrder](
[PKPurchaseOrderID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[PurchaseOrderNumber] [bigint] NULL,
[PurchaseOrderDate] [date] NULL,
[PurchaseOrderTime] [int] NULL,
[PurchaseOrderSupplierID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ShipToA1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ShipToA2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ShipToA3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ShipToA4] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PurchaseOrder] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PKPurchaseOrderID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseOrderLines](
[PKPurchaseOrderLineID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FKPurchaseOrderID] [bigint] NULL,
[Quantity] [smallint] NULL,
[Item] [nchar](25) NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[siteID] [nchar](10) NULL,
[UnitPrice] [money] NULL,
[LineTotal] [money] NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_PurchaseOrderLines] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 

(

    [PKPurchaseOrderLineID] ASC

)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

) ON [PRIMARY]



ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseOrderLines]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_PurchaseOrderLines_PurchaseOrder] FOREIGN KEY([FKPurchaseOrderID])

REFERENCES [dbo].[PurchaseOrder] ([PKPurchaseOrderID])


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseOrderLines] CHECK CONSTRAINT 
[FK_PurchaseOrderLines_PurchaseOrder]

GO
```

I want to achieve that in the background when user clicks the button both tables are updated.

I am not sure how I can link brand new row created in the PurchaseOrder table with FK in the PurchaseorderLine table.

What i plan to do for single user interface:

1. Insert New Order
2. Use Max(PKPurchaseOrderID) as FK for new order lines table.

How can I determine currently inserted Order ID(PKPurchaseOrderID) if multiple users are working/submitting orders at the same time. I am afraid order lines may be assigned to different orders if I use my plan. e.g.

Please advise.

I use SQL Server 2008 and Excel 2007/2010

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a stored procedure that inserts the new row and returns the ID with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Here's a decent article on the different "identity" methods in SQL Server.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/